# Don't open Java GUI when opened from a command-line

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, command-line, command-line-interface

I'm trying to achieve the following goals with the same jar file (if possible):

1. When command line arguments get specified, run as a CLI tool (without GUI) - that one's easy
2. When the user launches the application by double-clicking on the `.jar` file in Windows Explorer, or when launched using a double click in Nautilus, a GUI should be launched
3. When the user launches the program from a shell within a console/terminal (e.g. `cmd.exe`, `zsh` or `bash`), usage information should be printed and the program should exit after doing so (like when running `program -h` or program --help`), without opening a GUI.

A simple `args.length > 0` is not sufficient for this task, as a launch without any command line arguments should be handled differently when done via the terminal (using `java -jar program.jar`) compared to when done from Windows Explorer or Nautilus.

---

Is there a way of implementing the described behaviour, does my program have to check what its parent process is, or is something like this simply unfeasible/impossible?

Comment: what's stopping you from adding that option?

Comment: Start with [mcve] :) SO is not forum or tutorials point, thank you

Comment: Even that C# question gave you guidance what to do...

Comment: @Mickael
I hope my reworked question makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

you probably want something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        //use as command line tool
    } else {
        //start GUI
    }
}
```

You just need to check wether there are command line arguments or not.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but a launch from the CLI should never open a GUI, and display usage information instead. Only when launched from outside the command line the program should display a GUI. Sorry for the confusion; I edited my original question.

Comment: "but a launch from the CLI should never open a GUI" why not? have you ever tried executing an application through a terminal? if they have a gui it will open by typing in the application name and using options you can get other forms of information that may or may not also be present in the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Here comes OOP, Architechture, SOLID Principles, etc...

In SOLID Principles, there is the first principle which is `Single Responsibility Principle`, where one must separate every responsibility in its own object, every object has ONLY ONE responsibility. So, one must not put the application logic in the same UI object for example.

Your solution is to **separate application logic from the UI**, then make another interface which is a Command-line Interface.

For example: You want to make something that adds two numbers.

One makes `JFrame`, with two `JTextField` s , and a button. Then you add
a click listener on the button, that adds the two numbers and print it on a JLabel. But, if it is made like that, how could one make a CLI ?

In this case, you should make something like that, which handles the common logic between both Swing and CLI (application logic):

```
interface NumberAdditionResultAsString {
    void postResult(String result);
    void postError(Exception ex);
}

class NumberAdderFromStrings {
    void executeTheAddition(String num1, String num2, NumberAdditionResultAsString listener) {
        try {
            double n1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
            double n2 = Double.parseDouble(num2);
            listener.postResult(Double.toString(n1 + n2));
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            listener.postError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this application logic can be called from both Swing and CLI easily.
Also used the "callback" which is more suitable to handle lengthy operations which happens on other threads.

Also if you want something more complicated, you could use the `command` design pattern. Where all those "application logic", implements a single interface. Then both your UI and CLI calls them.

```
interface ApplicationCommand {
    Object execute(Object... parameters);
}
```

Then make something like that, in your main Application class:

```
Map<String, ApplicationCommand> commandMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then populate it like that:

```
commandMap.put("add", new ApplicationCommand() {
    @Override
    public Object execute(Object... parameters) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (Object one: parameters) {
            sum += Double.parseDouble(one.toString());
        }
        return sum;
    }
});
```

Well, this is not the best design. Better is to associate every String with a Factory object that creates the command, not with a command object itself. But this is for simplicity.

Advice: Read about

[Command design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command)

[Strategy design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)

[Abstract factory design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory)

[Flyweight design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight) (Can help in creating the command map properly)

[SOLID Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) (Read mainly: Single Responsibility, and Dependency Inversion)